# Remix warning: Gas requirement of function <function_name>() unknown or not constant

Tags: solidity, gas, remix

I have this warning in Remix Analysis tab for a basic send funds function:

```
function sendFunds(address receiver, uint amount) onlyOwner {
    if (this.balance < amount) throw;
    receiver.send(amount);
}
```

> Remix warning: Gas requirement of function () unknown or not constant.

I don't see why the gas cost would be unknown.

Can you help me out? Is there really a problem?

There is also this error which I think has no place there:

> Error: Type "address" not supported for state variable.

```
address public owner;
```

Comment: please provide the whole contract if it is possible

Comment: Sure, it's on [github](https://github.com/EtherDogs/PersonalBank/blob/master/PersonalBank.sol). But you can get the same result with a simple contract containing just what I mentioned in the question.

Comment: The link to github doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning about Gas requirements is correct!
If `receiver` is an ordinary address, the Gas usage is known. But if `receiver` is the address of a (payable) contract, the Gas requirements depend on the complexity of the contract code that is dealing with the incoming transaction.

Comment: OK, it makes sense. Thanks! Any idea about the error below?

And I have also the warning for this code: `arr.push(1);` where `uint[] public arr;`. Can't think of anything that would justify a warning for this.

Comment: I have the same problem. How does one fix this error/warning?  Why is it warning us about something we cant influence?  Why is it saying that MyContract.someVariable() unknown or not constant?  how can a class field be constant or known more that it is?